# Control password attribute with CHECK in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

PD:Some names are in Spanish, sorry.

I have a table containing columns `Usuario` and `Contraseña`.

For each one it will be necessary to determine: login user (unique in the system and identification) and access password (which must contain 5 letters and 2 numbers - exact length 7). Consider that the login name must have exactly 10 characters

The table created is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado
(
    Usuario varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE 
         CHECK(LEN([Usuario]) = 10),
    Contraseña varchar(7) NOT NULL 
         CHECK (LEN([Contraseña]) = (7) AND [Contraseña] LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND [Contraseña] LIKE '%[A-Z]%')
)
```

And the data is inserted like this:

```
INSERT INTO Empleado (Usuario, Contraseña) 
VALUES ('santiago21', 'qwerty1')

INSERT INTO Empleado (Usuario, Contraseña) 
VALUES ('FaaacuuUwU', 'qwertY1')
```

The problem is that the second insert should take it, but the first one should not, which it **DOES NOT DO**.

Does anyone know how I should do it? Thank you.

Comment: having a password of a fixed length  and exact no. of chars and numbers is almost certainly an attack vector. DON't store passwords! Store salted hashed passwords

Comment: @MitchWheat These days many people people prefer light sodium solutions, so maybe hold on the salt, but keep the hash `:-)`

Comment: without the salt, you are vulnerable to dictionary attacks.

Comment: Just joking of course...as long as the hash cannot easily be backed out, it should be fine.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : "as long as the hash cannot easily be backed out, it should be fine" - that's the point without the salt, you hash a dictionary of known  passwords and see if any hashes match....

Comment: @MitchWheat OK, fair enough, then my above comments should be taken with a grain of salt, I suppose.

Comment: advice on SO will be around for some time, and I want to make sure people are aware of the dangers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take advantage of SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator here:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado (
    Usuario varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK(LEN([Usuario]) = 10),
    Contraseña varchar(7) NOT NULL CHECK (
        LEN([Contraseña]) = 7 AND
        [Contraseña] LIKE '%[0-9]%[0-9]%' AND                                -- 2 numbers
        [Contraseña] LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%[A-Za-z]%')  -- 5 letters
    )
);
```

**Edit:**

In general you should *not* be storing clear text passwords in your database.  The reason for this is that should anyone (internal or external) gain access to your `Empleado` table, they would get access to *every* credential in your entire system.

Instead, a much safer approach would be to first irreversibly *hash* every password and then store the hash.  Then, in the unlikely event that someone undesirable might gain access to your table, they wouldn't get passwords, just usernames with some gibberish password hashes that they couldn't easily back out to the original passwords.

Comment: while this is a solution to OP question, you should not do this! DON't store passwords! Store salted hashed passwords

Comment: @MitchWheat I agree with your comment to the point where I actually have updated my answer with your caveats.